# How do I add my Stack Overflow reputation as a live badge on GitHub?

Tags: github, markdown, badge, shields.io

I am trying to add my Stack Overflow reputation as a live badge on my GitHub profile README.

First, I would need to somehow get my account information from Stack Overflow using some API. Next, I would need to extract the reputation and then pass it to another API which creates badges in Markdown.

Now, I have done some research and it seems like I am able to use the Stack Exchange [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) to attain my Stack Overflow account information in JSON format via an endpoint URL. Furthermore, Shield.io's [API](https://shields.io) will allow me to create badges from an endpoint URL which is perfect. However, Shields.io requires the endpoint to be in a specific JSON format.

So now to solve the puzzle, I need a third API which would be able to read and parse the JSON from the Stack Exchange API and then host an endpoint URL in the JSON format needed. RunKit's [API](https://runkit.com/home) seems to be able to do just that.

An example of what I am trying to achieve (but instead of commits it is my Stack Overflow reputation):

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First using stack exchange's **user** api [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids), you are able to attain your stack overflow account information in JSON format via an endpoint url. All you have to do is to specify your stack overflow user id in the id field and click **run** to generate the endpoint path. You can attain your stack overflow user id by clicking on your profile picture, it will then appear in the search bar.

[image]

Append the path generated to https://api.stackexchange.com to form the endpoint url.

My stack exchange endpoint url: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/9133459?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow

Now that we have our stack overflow information in JSON format, we can proceed to parse it and create a new endpoint which meets shields requirements. To do that you would have to create an account with [RunKit](https://runkit.com/home). Publish this piece of code on RunKit and make sure the node version is v4.9.1 (replace the url in the code with your own endpoint url generated previously):

```
// variables
var endpoint = require("@runkit/runkit/json-endpoint/1.0.0");
var fetch = require("node-fetch");
var url = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/9133459?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow";
let settings = { method: "Get" };  

// main function
endpoint(module.exports, async function()
{
    try {
       await fetch(url, settings)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                reputation = json["items"][0].reputation;
                if (reputation >= 1000) {
                    reputation = reputation / 1000;
                    reputation = Math.floor(reputation * 10) / 10;
                    // if first decimal place is 0
                    if ((reputation * 10) % 10 == 0) {
                        // round to int
                        reputation = Math.round(reputation);
                    }
                    reputation = reputation.toString();
                    reputation += "K";
                }
        });    
    } catch(e) {
        return {
            "schemaVersion": 1,
            "label": "STACKOVERFLOW REPUTATION",
            "message": "API ERROR",
            "color": "FF0000",
            "labelColor": "black",
            "style": "for-the-badge"
        }
    }
    return {
        "schemaVersion": 1,
        "label": "STACKOVERFLOW REPUTATION",
        "message": reputation,
        "color": "FE7A16",
        "labelColor": "black",
        "style": "for-the-badge"
    }
})
```

After publishing, click on the endpoint hyperlink at the top of the RunKit page to view the endpoint url which you are going to pass to shields in order to create the badge.

Here is my runkit endpoint url: https://stack-overflow-reputation-ciqil1ej93hq.runkit.sh

Now, all that is left is to go to shields.io's JSON endpoint badge page [here](https://shields.io/endpoint) and paste the url as such:

[image]

Besides *copying the badge url* option, you are also given the option to *copy the markdown* version, copy it and paste it in your GitHub profile *README*.

Markdown Outcome:

[image: Custom badge]

*Note: You can change the design of the badge by changing the JSON return statements in the RunKit code or overriding what you want to change in the JSON endpoint badge page. The attributes you can change are listed on the same page.*

Comment: is a great answer except the async/await then using callbacks

Comment: API ERROR IN 2021

Comment: Doesn't work in 2022. Problem after passung example code in RunKit:
{
  "error": "initialization_error",
  "message": "There was an error initalizing your endpoint."
}

Answer (score 52):

Another easy solution is to use the [flair feature](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flair) that's built into Stack Exchange:

1. [Edit your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current)
2. Click on "Flair" in the sidebar:

   [image: Screenshot of sidebar menu with Flair selected]
3. Copy the HTML shown on that page and paste it into your `README.md`

By default, flair images look like this:

[image: profile for Chris at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

There are options on the flair page for changing the theme as well as showing data from just one site (e.g. Stack Overflow) or including reputation from all Stack Exchange sites where you have over 200 points.

Answer (score 17):

To get StackOverflow reputation as a live badge, just replace my user **user id**
and **name** with yours!!

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/10249156/wasitshafi" target="_blank">
<img alt="StackOverflow"
src="https://stackoverflow-badge.vercel.app/?userID=10249156" />
</a>
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 10):

This is not working anymore...
Other solution,
First using stack exchange's user API  [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids), All you have to do is to specify your stack overflow user id in the id field and click run to generate the endpoint path. You can attain your stack overflow user id by clicking on your profile picture, it will then appear in the search bar.

Now, go to shields.io chat badge [here](https://shields.io/category/chat) and paste your url in the query section

[image]

in the query section you have to paste only the part that is after users/ eg:

> **This is a complete url:**
> /2.2/users/2096394?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow
> you **only need this part**:
> 2096394?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow

So that way you can get your badged working properly.

Comment: this gives "invalid parameter"

Comment: @LalitVavdara they should have changed something that made this solution to fail

Comment: any other option ?

Comment: @LalitVavdara I did a research and it works sometimes and sometimes show invalid parameter, i couldnt find any other solution apart from the other answers.

Answer (score 6):

For me [Shields.io](https://shields.io/category/chat)'s StackExchange reputation endpoint is working fine. Here is an example:

<del>It breaks sometimes. [Probable Reason.](https://github.com/badges/shields/issues/5415#issuecomment-675654337)</del> (Fixed)

```
![](https://img.shields.io/stackexchange/stackoverflow/r/<user_id>?color=orange&label=reputation&logo=stackoverflow&style=for-the-badge&cacheSeconds=86400)

<!-- hyperlinked with alt text and title: -->

[![<user_name>'s Stack Overflow Reputation](https://img.shields.io/stackexchange/stackoverflow/r/<user_id>?color=orange&label=reputation&logo=stackoverflow&style=for-the-badge)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/<user_id> "<user_name>'s Stack Overflow Reputation")
```

Put whatever you want in place of `<user_name>`, but replace `<user_id>` in above with your **StackOverflow** user ID. You can get it by visiting your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) and checking the profile URL. It is of the form: `https://stackoverflow.com/users/<user_id>/<user_name>`

[image: Brc-dd's Stack Overflow Reputation]

You can customize the colors/text/logo in the above badge if you wish.

Comment: Still gives invalid parameter for me

Comment: That link worked for me once but when I reload the page it says invalid parameters again

Comment: @mousetail Yeah, I can see now, I cleared the cache, and its showing invalid parameters. https://github.com/badges/shields/issues/5415

Answer (score 2):

@Chris' solution is the only one that seems to work at the time of answering to this. Given that, if the Flair you get from the StackOverflow Flair section doesn't seem all that good you can set the reputation **manually** as follows,

```html
<!-- Add your profile URL below-->
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/10883380/visal-rajapakse">
    <img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/Stack%20Overflow-802-F47F24">
                                                        <!-- ^ Change this to your reputation -->
</a>
```

The above will look like:

[image]

Comment: It's not the live-data solution we want, but it's the only one that works on this page right now, aside from "flair" which is really ugly.

Comment: A logo can be added with https://img.shields.io/badge/Reputation-802-F47F24?logo=stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/lowlighter/metrics can generate an SVG which can include a SO widget, and the SVG can be included in a GitHub profile README.md.  It has several styles and the SO plugin has several configuration options, but nothing approaches a shield layout.

Luckily it can generate a lot of other formats, including raw JSON that could be used by other tools to render a shield layout.

To create a shield, we can use its markdown format, and supply a template markdown file.

Incorporating @Visal-rajapakse's answer, I use the following markdown in my `TEMPLATE.md`:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/{{ plugins.stackoverflow.user.id }}">
    <img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/Reputation-{{ plugins.stackoverflow.user.reputation }}-F47F24?logo=stackoverflow&style=flat-square" alt="StackOverflow">
</a>
```

To activate this, create a GitHub Action in your "special" username repo to run lowlighters' metrics tool on that template to generate the README.md

Here is my GitHub action.  Substitute 'jayvdb' and '5037965' with your Github username and SO userid:

```
name: Metrics
on:
  # Schedule updates (once per day)
  schedule: [{cron: "0 1 * * *"}]
  # Lines below let you run workflow manually and on each commit (optional)
  workflow_dispatch:
  push: {branches: ["master", "main"]}

jobs:
  readme-template:
    name: Generate README
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Update README.md
        uses: lowlighter/metrics@main
        with:
          # Common config
          user: jayvdb
          token: ${{ secrets.METRICS_TOKEN }}
          output_action: skip-if-only-metadata-changed
          committer_branch: main
          committer_message: Update ${filename} - [GitHub Action]
          config_timezone: Etc/UTC

          # Input file
          markdown: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jayvdb/jayvdb/main/TEMPLATE.md

          # Output file
          template: markdown
          filename: README.md
          config_output: markdown

          plugin_stackoverflow: yes
          plugin_stackoverflow_user: 5037965
          plugin_stackoverflow_sections: answers-top, answers-recent
          plugin_stackoverflow_limit: 3
          plugin_stackoverflow_lines: 0
```

If you only want a SO widget, there are a few other readme widgets/generators with various builtin layouts, but none of them currently support a shield layout.  They are easier to use, and the authors may be willing to adding a shield layout.

- https://github.com/omidnikrah/github-readme-stackoverflow provides two layouts currently, and I've added an [issue](https://github.com/omidnikrah/github-readme-stackoverflow/issues/9) to add a shield layout.
- https://github.com/johannchopin/stackoverflow-readme-profile provides two layouts.
- https://github.com/harish-sethuraman/readme-components/blob/master/docs/stackoverflowCard.md (this one is like the SO 'Flair', but has a much nicer UX)

Answer (score 1):

There is https://shields.io/

Unfortunately is not working.

So I forked and cloned the shield repository. When I ran locally it worked.
So this means that the StackOverflow API probably has quota or is blacklisting the shield IO ip address.

What you can do is to fork this project and host it yourself (you can use something like heroku).